# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I got this problem when connecting to database.

> Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

I see a lot of same topics but there statement is different to me.

Code:

```
echo "Invalid file"; 

$filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]/','',$_FILES["file"]["name"]) . $extension;

$logo = upload/$filename

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "NLPZJNWF") or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db("masterlist") or die(mysql_error());

$strSQL = "INSERT INTO user(images) VALUES('$logo')";

mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: stop codding on a paper, guys...

Comment: Try $logo = "upload/$filename"; instead $logo = upload/$filename;

Comment: `$logo = upload/$filename` = `$logo = "upload/" . $filename;`?

Comment: i got this error sir Class when i try your code. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @ELGao learn the basic syntax before even go to Files and Databases...

Answer (score 0):

5th line should be:

```
$logo = "upload/$filename";
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? I see nothing wrong with this answer

Comment: You probably have another errors elsewhere, in this snippet there is no other error.